# Count DISTINCT Employees

Tags: sql, count, sum, distinct

Please assist me for counting a number of rows returned by my query showing a number of employees working for a specific month.

I have my Total Hours, Mode & Employee Name,but how can I return the exact number of employees working for the month?

`Count(DISTINCT LD.Employee)` Shows every employee occurs once, but how do I add the 1 up to get 52 as my final answer?

```
SELECT LD.Period, LD.EmOrg, LD.EmType, LD.Employee, 
    Sum(LD.RegHrs) AS 'Total Hours', Count(LD.RegHrs) AS 'Mode', 
    Count(DISTINCT LD.Employee) AS 'Counted Employees'
FROM SSI.dbo.LD LD
GROUP BY LD.Employee, LD.Period, LD.EmOrg, LD.EmType
HAVING (LD.EmOrg Like '%T00') AND (LD.EmType='S')
```

Data:

```
Period  EmOrg   EmType  Total Hours Mode    Employee Counted Employees
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 66  GOVINP1  1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   200 35  LANDCJ1  1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 34  WOODRE   1
201306  RSA/JNB/T00 S   160 33  MOKOHM1  1
201306  RSA/PLZ/T00 S   160 32  KAPPPJ   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   187 31  CAHISJ   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 31  ZEMUN    1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   190 28  SAULDD1  1
201306  RSA/DUR/T00 S   188 26  JEROP1   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   204 24  NGOBS1   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   201 23  DLAMMP   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   192 23  ZONDNS2  1
201306  RSA/PLZ/T00 S   160 22  MPHURK   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   186 21  DUBESE1  1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   187 21  MABAMS   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   189 21  MBELBV   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   188 21  MNDAMB   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   186 21  ZONDIPB1 1
201306  RSA/JNB/T00 S   180 20  BOKAML   1
201306  RSA/PTA/T00 S   180 20  DAVEJA   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  DLAMVK   1
201306  RSA/JNB/T00 S   163.5   20  ERLAME   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  HLONLA   1
201306  RSA/CPT/T00 S   179 20  HOUGHJ   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  KAFFS    1
201306  RSA/PTA/T00 S   180 20  KEYTDJ   1
201306  RSA/JNB/T00 S   180 20  KHATEK   1
201306  RSA/DUR/T00 S   180 20  KHUZB1   1
201306  RSA/PTA/T00 S   180 20  LEHLTJ   1
201306  RSA/JNB/T00 S   180 20  LETSMM2  1
201306  RSA/PTA/T00 S   170 20  MAKGMJ   1
201306  RSA/BDV/T00 S   160 20  MALEVT1  1
201306  RSA/JNB/T00 S   180 20  MAPHV1   1
201306  RSA/JNB/T00 S   180 20  MNGOTX   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  MTHETN1  1
201306  RSA/BDV/T00 S   180 20  MULAG1   1
201306  RSA/DUR/T00 S   180 20  NDLOCT1  1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  NDLOS    1
201306  RSA/BFN/T00 S   180 20  NELL     1
201306  RSA/PLZ/T00 S   180 20  OOSTLC   1
201306  RSA/CPT/T00 S   180 20  PAULDMR  1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  PHIRSN1  1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  RAMBD1   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  SANLLJ   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  SMITEP3  1
201306  RSA/CPT/T00 S   180 20  SOCEGR   1
201306  RSA/PZB/T00 S   180 20  SOKOV    1
201306  RSA/CPT/T00 S   180 20  TSHIJC   1
```

Comment: Please edit and indent your post in order to be a little more 'digestible'.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT( LD.Employee )` should give you the total number of entries in the table, `SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT LD.Employee )` will give you the number of DISTINCT Employees, who many people regardless of how many shifts they worked. If you don't want either of those numbers can you clarify your question. There seem to be 48 entries in your data set, where does the 52 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total number of Employees, you need to remove the `GROUP BY LD.Employee` clause.

That's why your `COUNT( LD.Employee )` is always one. Try removing the `GROUP`

Comment: _Willsaw Media_
I'm aware I'm using the **LD.Employee** as a in an aggregate function & it should not be included in the group function,but when I remove it **ODBC SQL Server** gives me an error **Column 'SSI.dbo.LDEmployee' is invalid in the select list becacause it is not contained in either an aggregate function OR the GROUP BY clause**.
Removing the GROUP BY changed the outcome of my output significantly

Let me show you my current table now...

Comment: Sorry Im new still not too good at using this forum

Period EmOrg EmType Total Hours Mode Counted Employees 201306 RSA/PZB/T00 S 4450 600 24 201306 RSA/JNB/T00 S 1223.5 153 7 201306 RSA/CPT/T00 S 719 80 4 201306 RSA/PTA/T00 S 710 80 4 201306 RSA/PLZ/T00 S 500 74 3 201306 RSA/DUR/T00 S 548 66 3 201306 >RSA/BDV/T00 S 340 40 2 201306 RSA/BFN/T00 S 180 20 1

Comment: Can you write out the desired results from your query? Do you just want 1 single line back?

Comment: All I want to achieve in this select statement is to get a value of all the returned rows irrespective of how they are added to get me the value 48. _It is pointless for me to create a query that returns the employees yet I have to count them again manually on the spresdsheet for a returned period._

#Answer should be the same as the 1 on the question,but should increment from **1 to 48**

Comment: As **LD.Employee** is varchar it makes it impossible for me to use the SUM function as I can only use TO_CHAR if the name can be represented in numbers e.g '201201'